# Error Sideloading Android L

Tags: adb, rom-flashing, signature-error

I am trying to update my Nexus 7 (2013) WiFi to Android 5.0 with `adb sideload`. I get this error:

```
Finding update package...
Opening update package...
Verifying update package...
E:footer is wrong
E:signature verification failed
Installation aborted.
```

I have the file (razor). It is a .tgz file, so I entered into the command prompt (I opened inside SDK platorm-tools) and ran `adb sideload beaverlog.tgz` and it gave me that error (beaverlog is what I named the file). The instructions also said to do it as a .zip file but I couldn't find a .zip file.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have a .tgz file, I would assume you downloaded the [factory image](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images) for your device. You cannot use `adb sideload` with those archives. They are not packaged for that. You note in your comment:

> The instructions also said to do it as a .zip

...and the instructions are correct. If you find that your environment is deviating from the stated instructions, then it is quite often an indication that you are not following the process the way it is intended. In this situation, luckily, the recovery system bails out without damaging your device, but in the future it would be a good idea to take some care when attempting to install images to your device.

The top of the factory images page you got the update from has *different instructions* for flashing the contents of the archive. You need to either follow **those** steps or obtain a copy of the update in a .zip format that is compatible with recovery-based installation.

If you intend to use the factory image, the proper steps are:

> **Caution: Flashing a new system image deletes all user data. Be certain to first backup any personal data such as photos.**
>
> 1. Download the appropriate system image for your device below, then unzip it to a safe directory.
> 2. Connect your device to your computer over USB.
> 3. Start the device in fastboot mode with one of the following methods:
>
>    - Using the adb tool: With the device powered on, execute:
>
>      ```
>      adb reboot bootloader
>      ```
>    - Using a key combo: Turn the device off, then turn it on and immediately hold down the relevant key combination for your device.
>        For example, to put a Nexus 5 ("hammerhead") into fastboot mode, press
>        and hold Volume Up + Volume Down + Power as the device begins booting
>        up.
> 4. If necessary, unlock the device's bootloader by running:
>
>    ```
>    fastboot oem unlock
>    ```
> 5. The target device will show you a confirmation screen. (This erases all data on the target device.)
> 6. Open a terminal and navigate to the unzipped system image directory.
> 7. Execute the `flash-all` script. This script installs the necessary bootloader, baseband firmware(s), and operating system.

If you are using Windows, you will need third-party software to extract the .tgz archive, because Windows does not support it natively. [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) is a free (and popular) option.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue, my device is hanged in booting, it was displaying "Google" logo and it didn't start.

When I tried to update with "adb sideload", I got following error:

```
Finding update package...
Opening update package...
Verifying update package...
E:footer is wrong
E:signature verification failed
Installation aborted.
```

Then, I tried using Nexus tool kit.

I believe, it works in unlocked and rooted mobiles only

Please try your luck by following below steps.

1. Install Nexus Root Toolkit ( I used v2.0.5)
2. Connect your device to PC using USB cable. Make sure your drivers are successfully recognized or just click on 'Full driver installation guide - Automatic + Manual)- don't worry about step 2.
3. Choose your device model and Android version ( I had Android 5.1.0 LMY470)
4. Reboot your device to Bootloader menu, Choose Recovery mode (I had Clockwork recovery mode) > Install zip > Choose `sideload`.
5. Now, click on `Flash Stock + Unroot` > ok > in 'Factory images', choose your required image ( I would recommend don't browse image from PC). In choice section, use "Automatically". In settings section, un-check all. And then click ok. It will download.
6. Once it completes, Nexus toolkit will try to boot to Bootloader menu. Now, you should do it manually by choosing `go back back` > `advanced` > `reboot bootloader`.

That's it, it will install new system.

Please note, first bootup will take much time.